# Git pull fails with "mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: git

I am trying to pull the repository with `git pull` and I keep getting the following error:

```
remote: Counting objects: 142, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (134/134), done.
remote: Total 142 (delta 73), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (142/142), 1.11 MiB | 1.02 MiB/s, done.
fatal: mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I changed `packSizeLimit`, `deltaCacheSize`, and `windowMemory` to 4m and did a `git repack`, but it didn't help. My repository contains a couple of images unfortunately, and the server it is on is really weak. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Which server software are you using?

Comment: What is the git version you are running with ?

Comment: Move to a more powerful server?

Comment: The issue is on your end, not on the server end.  Server problems get prefixed with `remote:`.  You can try fussing with your packing config on your end...